# How to prevent nested tmux session in a new login shell?

Tags: ssh, authentication, environment-variables, tmux, su

Almost all solutions ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43601/how-can-i-set-my-default-shell-to-start-up-tmux), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420733/dont-nest-tmux-in-a-remote-ssh-shell)) to set tmux run at shell startup depend on some environment variables like `$TMUX`, `$TERM` etc. But when we start a login shell such as by `su -`, all variables are cleared except `$TERM`. So we can rely on `$TERM` to avoid starting nested sessions. Let's say the default `$TERM` is `xterm` and we set `screen` in `.tmux.conf` to identify we are in a TMUX session. This works fine for local login.

Now, two machines A and B use same rule to control nested sessions and we are in a tmux session on machine A. When we login remotely (through `ssh`) from A to B, tmux session won't start on B because `$TERM` is already set to `screen`.

So, isn't there a way to find out that we are already in a tmux session without depending on environment variables?

**PS:**

I'm posting a workaround as answer that I use to achieve the above said behavior. But a more accurate and better method such as that may work using tmux commands will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you're making this harder than necessary. For the `su -` case just augment the `su` config to pass through the `TMUX` var. Alternatively, do you really want a root login to automatically start a tmux session if it isn't already in a session? That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @KurtisRader practically I have a more complex situation which I didn't post here to keep things simple. But the point is that passing variables between different machines and different environments through different login mechanisms becomes too difficult itself. So I don't want to stick with that. And the root thing I just mentioned to explain my problem. I don't start tmux sessions with root login. But still it could be a requirement by someone even if we consider it a bad practice :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution works by finding out if current terminal is connected to a tmux server running on the same machine. In order to find out the connection, we will make use of a pseudoterminal pair and [I/O statistics](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt?id=HEAD#n1563) hack.
However it may fail if `/proc`fs or `/dev` files are not read-able / write-able by the user. For instance if tmux server was launched by root user, a non-root user won't be able to find it.
Also, we may get false positives if tmux server is receiving data from some other source at the same time we are trying to write zeros to it.

Put this at the end of `.bashrc` or other shell startup file you want:

```
# ~/.bashrc

# don't waste time if $TMUX environemnt variable is set
[ -z $TMUX ] || return

# don't start a tmux session if current shell is not connected to a terminal
pts=$(tty) || return

# find out processes connected to master pseudoterminal
for ptm in $(fuser /dev/ptmx 2>/dev/null)
do
    # ignore process if it's not a tmux server
    grep -q tmux /proc/$ptm/comm || continue
    # number of bytes already read by tmux server
    rchar_old=$(awk '/rchar/ {print $2}' /proc/$ptm/io)
    # write out 1000 bytes to current slave pseudoterminal terminal
    dd bs=1 count=1000 if=/dev/zero of=$pts &>/dev/null
    # read number of bytes again and find difference
    diff=$(( $(awk '/rchar/ {print $2}' /proc/$ptm/io) - rchar_old ))
    # if it equals 1000, current terminal is connected to tmux server
    # however diff comes greater than 1000 most of the times
    [ $diff -ge 1000 ] && return
done

# start or attach to a tmux session
echo 'Press any key to interrupt tmux session.'
read -st1 key && return

# connect to a detached session if exists for current user
session=($(tmux list-sessions 2>/dev/null | sed -n '/(attached)/!s/:.*r//p'))
[ -z $session ] || exec tmux a -t ${session[0]}

# start a new session after all
exec tmux
```